# How to fix ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis while using int or integer with specified size

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried using integer and int will size 50 and i was getting error but when i tried creating the same table without any specified size I was able to create the table

Here is the picture of the error
[image]

```
SQL> create table employees
  2  (employee_number integer(50) not null primary key,
  3  last_name char(50) not null,
  4  first_name char(50) not null,
  5  Salary integer(20),
  6  Dept_id integer);
(employee_number integer(50) not null primary key,
                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

```
SQL> create table employees
  2  (employee_number int(50) not null primary key,
  3  last_name char(50) not null,
  4  first_name char(50) not null,
  5  Salary int(20),
  6  Dept_id int);
(employee_number int(50) not null primary key,
                    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Comment: When you're asking for help, please don't post screenshots or photographs. Cut & paste the text into the reddit message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: Sure will keep these points in my mind from next time . Thanks for the inputs!

Comment: Oracle is not the SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah I know , int and integer with size specified are not working on both

Comment: Also, I don't know about SQL Server but `char` is never useful in Oracle - use `varchar2`.

Comment: Any specific reason to use varchar2 rather than char?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF), the ANSI `int` or `integer` data type is actually mapped to Oracle data type `NUMBER(38)`.

So you can't add a size parameter to it.

Comment: The answer would be more useful (to the OP and to future readers) if, in addition to what you wrote, it would also show how to achieve the intended result in Oracle: declare the column as `number(20,0)` (instead of `integer(20)`).

Comment: @mathguy - that's fair. Since OP wanted to declare `integer(50)`, I think they also might need an explanation of precision vs. whatever idea of integer size they're thinking of.